# dimple multiple line with multiple column data

Tags: javascript, charts, dimple.js

how can i make a multiple line chart with multiple column data?
Data exemple:

```
var data75 = [{"d":1,'a1':50,'a2':70},
{"d":2,'a1':90,'a2':71},
{"d":3,'a1':40,'a2':90},
{"d":4,'a1':15,'a2':70},
{"d":5,'a1':150,'a2':60},
{"d":6,'a1':53,'a2':20},
{"d":7,'a1':59,'a2':40},
{"d":8,'a1':30,'a2':50},
{"d":9,'a1':70,'a2':77},
{"d":10,'a1':52,'a2':72},
{"d":11,'a1':56,'a2':10},
{"d":12,'a1':57,'a2':40},];
```

d = axis x;
a1 and a2 = axis y in 2 diferent series;

[image: Exemple]

Comment: You might want to do some research first. Then write some code. Um, debugging, that's a good one!

Comment: Check out [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

Answer (score 5):

1. Create SVG Object

   ```
   var svg = dimple.newSvg('#div', 400, 200);
   ```
2. Create Graph

   ```
   var chart = dimple.chart(svg, data75);
   chart.setBounds(20, 20, 360, 160);
   ```
3. Create /or/ Assign Axis for Chart

   ```
   var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "x");
   var y1 = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "a1");
   var y2 = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "a2");
   ```
4. Add Series (Pair of axis make a series)

   ```
   myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line, [x, y1]);
   myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line, [x, y2]);
   ```
5. Draw Chart

   ```
   myChart.draw();
   ```